# Bsearch and junk values in the comparison function

Tags: c, bsearch

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define DICT_BUFSIZE 64

int compar(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    const char* c1 = (const char*)a;
    const char* c2 = (const char*)b;

    printf("c1: %s | c2: %s\n", c1, c2);

    return strcmp(c1, c2);
}

int main (void)
{
    FILE*     fdict;
    uint32_t  i;
    char**    dict = NULL;
    size_t    size = 0;
    size_t    size_alloced = 0;
    char      buf[DICT_BUFSIZE];

    fdict = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
    if (!fdict) {
        printf("Could not open \"%s\": %s\n", "usr/share/dict/words", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; fgets(buf, DICT_BUFSIZE, fdict); ++i) {
        size_t len;

        if (i == size_alloced) {
            dict = realloc(dict, (i +50000) * sizeof(*dict));
            size_alloced += 50000;
        }
        len = strlen(buf);
        dict[i] = malloc(len);

        memcpy(dict[i], buf, len -1);
        dict[i][len -1] = '\0';
    }
    size = i;

    //for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        //printf("%s\n", dict[i]);

    if(bsearch("company", dict, size, sizeof(*dict), compar))
        printf("Found!\n");

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        free(dict[i]);
    free(dict);

    fclose(fdict);

    return 0;
}
```

In the "compar" function the "c1" variable (the key to be searched) is displayed correctly, however there's junk output in the v2 variable.

Here's a sample output:

```
c1: company | c2: ���
c1: company | c2: �$z
c1: company | c2: ��I
c1: company | c2: ��7
c1: company | c2: P�.
c1: company | c2: �b3
c1: company | c2: �1
c1: company | c2: P�/
c1: company | c2: ��0
c1: company | c2: PC0
c1: company | c2: @g0
c1: company | c2:  y0
c1: company | c2: 0�0
c1: company | c2: ��0
c1: company | c2: `�0
c1: company | c2: ��0
c1: company | c2: 
c1: company | c2: P�0
```

I cannot understand this behaviour.

Comment: I don't think sizeof(*dict) has the value you think it does.

Comment: I immediately thought of that as a culprit but I fail to see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were searching an array of `int`, you'd be converting the `const void *` arguments to your compare function to `int *`, would you not?

You're searching an array of `char *`, so you need to be converting the `const void *` arguments to `char **` — and you need to pass a `char **` argument for the value to be found.

The changes required to your code are minimal but crucial:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define DICT_BUFSIZE 64

static int compar(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *c1 = *(const char **)a;
    const char *c2 = *(const char **)b;

    printf("c1: %s | c2: %s\n", c1, c2);

    return strcmp(c1, c2);
}

int main (void)
{
    FILE*     fdict;
    uint32_t  i;
    char**    dict = NULL;
    size_t    size = 0;
    size_t    size_alloced = 0;
    char      buf[DICT_BUFSIZE];
    const char *file = "/usr/share/dict/words";

    fdict = fopen(file, "r");
    if (!fdict) {
        printf("Could not open \"%s\": %s\n", file, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; fgets(buf, DICT_BUFSIZE, fdict); ++i) {
        size_t len;

        if (i == size_alloced) {
            dict = realloc(dict, (i +50000) * sizeof(*dict));
            size_alloced += 50000;
        }
        len = strlen(buf);
        dict[i] = malloc(len);

        memcpy(dict[i], buf, len -1);
        dict[i][len -1] = '\0';
    }
    size = i;

    //for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        //printf("%s\n", dict[i]);

    const char *search = "company";
    if(bsearch(&search, dict, size, sizeof(*dict), compar))
        printf("Found!\n");

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        free(dict[i]);
    free(dict);

    fclose(fdict);

    return 0;
}
```

The comparator function now expects two `char **` values, and captures the string that each of those points to.

The first argument to the call needs to be the address of a `char *` variable; hence the addition of variable `const char *search = "company";`.

Minor cleanups include make the comparator function static (mainly to satisfy my pedantic default compilation options — though it is best if functions are declared before they're defined), and using variable `const char *file = "/usr/share/dict/words";` to avoid (near) repetition between the call to `fopen()` and the error message.

Sample output (run on a Mac with macOS Sierra 10.12.3):

```
c1: company | c2: modifier
c1: company | c2: eagle
c1: company | c2: Canarian
c1: company | c2: counteridea
c1: company | c2: citropten
c1: company | c2: compulsoriness
c1: company | c2: coelenteric
c1: company | c2: Colossian
c1: company | c2: commonable
c1: company | c2: compilation
c1: company | c2: compagination
c1: company | c2: compatriot
c1: company | c2: comparition
c1: company | c2: comparable
c1: company | c2: companionate
c1: company | c2: companionway
c1: company | c2: comparability
c1: company | c2: company
Found!
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was interesting! A correction: the "key" in bsearch does not be passed as a pointer to pointer, as it was apparent by its successful printing on my example. Apart from that, I was also baffled by how the second example in the following website works without the issues of my program: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/

Comment: If you're going to use the same compare function with `qsort()` — which would allow you to sort the data — you definitely need both arguments to be the same type. The key in `bsearch()` is always passed as the first argument, so you could use `static int compar(const void *a, const void *b)
{ const char *c1 = (const char *)a; const char *c2 = *(const char **)b;` with asymmetric casting, but it seems silly to have to create one function for sorting and another for searching. So, yes, if you're only ever going to use the comparator with `bsearch()`, you can do as you suggest. I wouldn't do it.

Comment: The second example in the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/ link is searching `char strvalues[][20] = {"some","example","strings","here"};`, not `char *strvalues[] = {"some","example","strings","here"};` — and the difference really matters.  The latter is equivalent to what you've got.

Comment: *"Re: it is best if functions are declared before they're defined." ----> Why is that so?

Comment: @Haris: there are various ways of looking at that.  First, if the function is non-static, it will be referenced from some other source file too (because it would be static if it were not referenced elsewhere — I wish C had a mechanism for making functions static by default), and therefore there will be a header that declares the function, and that header will be included both where the function is defined and where it is used, so the non-static function will automatically be declared before being defined.  If you aren't practising that sort of sanitary coding, it's time to clean up.

Comment: @Haris: if the function is static, then my comment doesn't have to be applied — defining the function as static before it is used is fine (but it needs to be declared before it is used, of course — even if that means copying a lot of what would be in the function definition into a function declaration near the top of the file).  Of course, C99 or later requires all functions to be declared before they are used (except for `main()`).

Comment: There's also the question of compiler options.  GCC has options such as `-Wmissing-prototypes`, `-Wstrict-prototypes`, `-Wold-style-declaration`, `-Wold-style-definition` — some of which are activated by `-Wall` and/or `-Wextra`.  Declaring (non-static) functions before they are defined avoids warnings (errors because I use `-Werror` to make sure all warnings are treated as errors).  So, it is all part of my "automatic" C regime.  Non-static functions are declared before they're defined; static functions can be defined without a prior prototype, and then must be defined before they're used.

Comment: I appreciate those insights.